# Extracting Number from URL in Java via Regex

Tags: java, regex

Take URL `http://www.abc.com/alpha/beta/33445566778899/gamma/delta`

i need to return the number `33445566778899` (with forward slashes removed, number is of variable length but between 10 & 20 digits)

Simple enough (or so i thought) except everything I've tried doesn't seem to work but why?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\/([0-9])\\d{10,20}\\/");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fullUrl);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one-liner:

```
String number = url.replaceAll(".*/(\\d{10,20})/.*", "$1");
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `/` after the number group as well (I noticed you added it before in an edit)? Otherwise it'd find the number in `http://www.abc.com/alpha/beta/33445566778899xyz/gamma/delta` which doesn't not seem to be expected.

Comment: @Gorkk yes, for ccompleteness it should be there. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This regex works -

```
"\\/(\\d{10,20})\\/"
```

Testing it-

```
String fullUrl = "http://www.abc.com/alpha/beta/33445566778899/gamma/delta";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\/(\\d{10,20})\\/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fullUrl);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

OUTPUT - `33445566778899`

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
String url = "http://www.abc.com/alpha/beta/33445566778899/gamma/delta";
String digitStr = null;
for(String str : url.split("/")){
    System.out.println(str);
    if(str.matches("[0-9]{10,20}")){
        digitStr = str;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(digitStr);
```

Output:

```
33445566778899
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying it "doesn't seem to work", you should have given use what it was returning. Testing it confirmed what I thought: your code would return `3` for this input.

This is simply because your regexp as written will capture a digit following a `/` and followed by 10 to 20 digits themselves followed by a `/`.

The regex you want is `"/(\\d{10,20})/"` (you don't need to escape the `/`). Below you'll find the code I tested this with.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String src = "http://www.abc.com/alpha/beta/33445566778899/gamma/delta";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/(\\d{10,20})/");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(src);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```